# Why does mouse and keyboard input get disabled on the lock screen when the screen rotates?

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, mouse, lock-screen, touchscreen

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on a Dell Inspiron. Sometimes after waking the laptop after it has been closed, the screen is in a different orientation (e.g. upside down presumably depending on how it was positioned), and it says "swipe up to unlock", which doesn't normally appear on the lock screen. More significantly, the laptop won't accept keyboard of mouse input until it had been rebooted.

This seems to be a "tablet mode", and I can interact with it via the touch screen, including logging in and activating a reboot, but the keyboard and mouse get ignored until the reboot happens. How can I prevent this from happening?